# How can I flash CyanogenMod, or another mod, on an AT&T locked Note 2?

Tags: rom-flashing, samsung-galaxy-note-2

My Note II has a lot of useless AT&T apps, and I would also like some features that require root and are available on CyanogenMod.

Is there an easy way to flash CyanogenMod on a locked Note 2?

I wouldn't mind things like worse battery life and Bluetooth not working. The pen working would be nice, but it's not essential as well. I couldn't care less about NFC and other shenanigans like the proximity gesture commands.